# How to get location Lat and Long just from GPS not google api in android?

Tags: android, gps, location

I have developed an app which works fine when using Google API for location but when I select GPS only in my smartphone, it says no location. What is wrong with my below code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(theButtonListener);

    locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = locationManager
              .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(enabled)
    {
        //Log.d(TAG,"YES enabled");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enabled", 2000).show();
    }
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, provider.toString(), 5000).show();
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    //Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
          //Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, location.toString(), 10000).show();
        onLocationChanged(location); //<6>
        }
    else
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No location", 5000).show();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 400, 1, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged with location " + location.toString());
    String text = String.format("Lat:\t %f\nLong:\t %f\nAlt:\t %f\nBearing:\t %f",    location.getLatitude(), 
                  location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude(), location.getBearing());
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, 10000).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //         locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location =   locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, provider.toString(), 5000).show();
        //Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
              //Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, location.toString(), 10000).show();
            onLocationChanged(location); //<6>
            }
        else
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No location", 5000).show();

    }
};
```

By the way, how google API works internally, how it finds what is my LAT and LON?

Comment: `getLastKnownLocation` can return null

Comment: If there is no signal from GPS (or never was) then the location can be null. Are you outside, are you waiting for the GPS fix, is it even coming? It can take a while..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

onLocationChanged is a callback, meaning it is called by the system when the location changes. It is event driven, you should not call it explicitly. You must wait until the GPS gets a fix, you can't get one immediately. When the app is first run, then there may not be a 'last location', hence it will return null.